# Bash - move a file to a specific path inside a zip file

Tags: bash, zip, 7zip

I have a file that placed in the following directory:

```
folder/another_folder/file_to_add.xml
```

Now, what I want to do is simply add the file to a folder in the zip

For example this is my zip content:

```
my_zip.zip/folder/another_folder
```

How can I add the '**file_to_add.xml**' to the '**another_folder**'?

```
my_zip.zip/folder/another_folder/file_to_add.xml
```

**Important!**

I don't want to create folders with the same names and add them.

There is a command that allow me to do that?

Thanks

Comment: This is a very interesting question. Perhaps it would get more answers if it were moved to http://unix.stackexchange.com/, where bash scripting is often discussed extensively.

Comment: In which folder is the zip folder located?

Comment: In the same folder with the 'folder': /home/my_zip.zip - /home/folder

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke python for this:

```
#!/bin/bash
python -c '
import zipfile as zf, sys
z=zf.ZipFile(sys.argv[1], "a")
z.write(sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3])
z.close()
' my_zip.zip your/existing/file_to_add.xml directory_in_zip/file_to_add.xml
```

This will open `my_zip.zip` and add `your/existing/file_to_add.txt` from the file system as `directory_in_zip/file_to_add.xml` in the zip file.